# iterating over list with different elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have three types of element: a dict, a list with one dict, and a list with multiple dicts.

```
a = {"foo":1}
b = [{"foo":2}]
c = [{"foo":3}, {"foo":4}]
list = [a, b, c]
```

I want to be print all four values. The only ways I came up with were either checking `type()` of each element of `list`, or using `try` and `except`, like so:

```
for i in list:
    try:                     # i is a dict
        print(i["foo"])
    except:                  # i a list
        for e in i:
            print(e["foo"])
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isinstance`

**Ex:**

```
a = {"foo":1}
b = [{"foo":2}]
c = [{"foo":3}, {"foo":4}]
l = [a, b, c]

for i in l:
    if isinstance(i, dict):     #Check if dict object
        print(i["foo"])
    elif isinstance(i, list):   #Check if list object
        for j in i:
            print(j["foo"])
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the datatype explicitly:

```
mylist = [a, b, c]

for i in mylist:
    if isinstance(i,dict):
        print(i["foo"])
    elif isinstance(i,list):
        for e in i:
            print(e["foo"])
```

But this *won't work* if you call your variable `list`. This snippet illustrates why you should not do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator with your `try` / `except` idea:

```
a = {"foo":1}
b = [{"foo":2}]
c = [{"foo":3}, {"foo":4}]
L = [a, b, c]

def get_values(x):
    for i in x:
        try:
            yield i['foo']
        except TypeError:
            yield from get_values(i)

res = list(get_values(L))  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Alternatively, using `isinstance:

```
def get_values(x):
    for i in x:
        if isinstance(i, dict):
            yield i['foo']
        else:
            yield from get_values(i)
```

Note you should *never* name variables after built-ins, e.g. use `list_` or `L` instead of `list`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it for more nested elements like a list in a dict in a list you can create a function for every possible datatype.

```
class Printer():
    def print_element(self, element):
        if isinstance(element, dict):
            self._print_dict(element)
        elif isinstance(element, list):
            self._print_list(element)
        else:
            print(element)

    def _print_dict(self, element):
        for key,value in element.items():
            self.print_element(value)

    def _print_list(self, element):
        for value in element:
            self.print_element(value)

a = {"foo":1}
b = [{"foo":2}]
c = [{"foo":3}, {"foo":4}, [1, {"foo":[9,8,7,6]}]]

Printer().print_element(c)
```

Output:

```
3
4
1
9
8
7
6
```